# Type of singularity of $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-e^z}$ in $z_0 = 0$ with Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I need to  classify the pole $z_0=0$  of the following function-
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-e^z}$$
The only method that I know is to expand the function in its Laurent Series. I cannot use Bernoulli Numbers since I have not viewed in class.
I began by expanding $e^z$ as its Taylor series, but I got a problem when I was constructing de funcion $f(z)$.

I got stucked in the following

$$ \frac{1}{1-e^z} = \frac{1}{1-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}} $$

Also I tried to substitute de Taylor series of $e^z$ in the expansion os $Log(1+z)$ and the geometric series; nonetheless, I got a double series in each case.

This topic is very new form me. Any help is aprecciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you looking for a finite part of the Laurent series, or the entire Laurent series? The connection with Bernoulli numbers that you mention shows that there isn't going to be a simple way to get the entire Laurent series.

Comment: This function has poles at $z=2\pi i k, k \in \mathbb Z$.  So it has different Laurent series in different annuli separated by these.  Perhaps, for example, you want the Laurent series valid in $0 < |z| < 2\pi$.

Comment: In response to both of you, actually I'm trying to look what type of pole has the function in $z_0=0$, but the only examples that I make were by expanding the funcion in tis Laurent Series. I shall make a correction in the question, thank you both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple pole. An easy way to check this is to see that $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z}{1-e^z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{-e^z}=-1$(which can be done by expanding the Taylor series of $e^z$ or you can just divide the numerator and denominator by z and use that $1-e^z$ is holomorphic at 0.)